# Como elaborar políticas de Check-In somente após um Get Last Version no TFS 2012?

Tags: team-foundation-server

Gostaria de saber se é possível e como faço para travar o Check In caso o Desenvolvedor não tenha feito o Get Last Version antes de tentar subir, tendo em vista que no cenário apresentado não possua Serviço Team Foundation Build implantado?

Answer (score 1):

Existe o [TFS Checkin Policy](http://tfsensurelatest.codeplex.com/), que pode ser instalado como um plugin para o Visual Studio. Basta instalar na máquina e usar o TFS normalmente.

A partir da versão 2010 do Visual Studio, você pode [realizar a sequência de passos descrita aqui](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385989(v=vs.100).aspx):

- No menu do Visual Studio, clique em <kbd>Team</kbd> > <kbd>Project Settings</kbd> > <kbd>Source Control</kbd>;
- Na janela de configurações que aparecer, escolha a aba <kbd>Check-out Settings</kbd>;
- Marque a opção <kbd>Enable Get Latest on Check-out</kbd>;
- Clique em <kbd>Ok</kbd>.